# Browser doesn't show any XML tag tree

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I am calling a REST based service and the URL that I am calling doesn't show any XML tags but by pressing F12 (developer mode) I found out that the response code is 200 meaning it is successful.

I am kind of lost here. What I am suppose to do at the back end because I also get `premature end of file exception`. If I am getting a 200 response code then why it is throwing `premature end of file exception`?

Thanks...

Comment: It is possibly returning an empty response.

Comment: But this service is suppose to validate an Email address.

Answer (score 0):

So this is for the starters. While calling a third party service we need to make sure that we are providing the authentication credentials as part of the request header. In my case I wasn't supplying them but the strange thing was that I was getting a OK response but down the line it was throwing `premature end of file` exception.

So once I provided the credentials for the service it went through and now I can see the beautiful XML payload.

Happy coding...